# Sharing a global variable between 2 controllers FAILED after a GET request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using 2 different controllers sharing a global value currentOpenningFolder. I want that 2 controllers can both sync to that variable no matter what. But in this example, in the GET request I change the variable in the first controller but I can't view that variable in the second controller. Instead it shows the initial value of `currentOpenningFolder`. Any ideas why this may be happening?

```
      angular.module('scopeExample', [])   
.controller('MyController', ['$scope','currentOpenningFolder','$http', function($scope,currentOpenningFolder,$http) {
            $scope.sayHello = function() {

          $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/chuson1996').then(function(obj){
            currentOpenningFolder = obj;
            console.log(currentOpenningFolder);
          })
        };
      }])
      .controller('MyController2', ['$scope','currentOpenningFolder', function($scope,currentOpenningFolder) {
        $scope.sayHello = function() {
          $scope.currentOpenningFolder = currentOpenningFolder;
          console.log($scope.currentOpenningFolder);
        };
      }])
      .value('currentOpenningFolder',{});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign an object to other object like this:

```
currentOpenningFolder = obj;
```

if you assign as this,`currentOpenningFolder`  will loose reference to original object and refer to other object `obj`. so best way to do this is to create a property of `currentOpenningFolder` and assign object to that prperty like this :

```
currentOpenningFolder.prop = obj;
```

and then access this to other controller like:

```
$scope.currentOpenningFolder = currentOpenningFolder.prop;
```

**Edited:**

Try this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0mtY3WjioybbnIZm4xW?p=preview)

Comment: could you please create plunkr or fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple fix is to extend the existing object instead of replacing it. Replacing it is causing references to be broken

Change

```
currentOpenningFolder = obj;
```

To

```
angular.extend(currentOpenningFolder , obj);
```

This leaves the existing object intact ( and the other references) and merges changes into it.

Also in the controllers I'm not sure why you set the scope variable that points to `currentOpenningFolder` within a function. You likely want to declare it outside the function

Without seeing more code it seems like `$scope.sayHello=function(...` should be replaced with `$scope.currentOpenningFolder = currentOpenningFolder;`